# Как сделать чтобы QPainter рисовал не по целым числам?

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter, qdoublespinbox

`QPainer` рисует только по целым числам, если задать не целыми числами координаты, то программа просто не работает, с целыми же всё работает.

Можно как-то перенастроить, чтобы рисовало и по не целым числам?

Comment: "не целыми" это как? полтора пикселя?

Comment: @Sergey Tatarintsev например 0.5 или 1.2 - не целые

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, ВСЕГДА предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример и хорошо рассказывайте что вы хотите сделать.

Если вы развиваете тему вашего предыдущего вопроса, то не понятно какие у вас проблемы.

> void QPainter::[**drawRect**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#drawRect)(const **QRectF** &rectangle)
>
> Рисует current прямоугольник текущими pen и brush.

Я переписал класс `Tab_2Widget()` чтобы продемонстрировать вам, что проблем нет.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(614, 478)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

        self.tab = Tab_1Widget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 70, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        
        self.tab_2 = Tab_2Widget()                                  # +++
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
# убрал vvv        
        '''
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 90, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_2)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 90, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        '''

        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 1"))
# убрал       self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Tab 2"))


class Tab_1Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flag = False
        self.c = 0    

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flag:
            qp = QPainter()
            qp.begin(self)
            self.drawRectangles(qp)
            qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):
        qp.drawRect(10, 150, self.c, 60)

        
class Tab_2Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
# !!!   установил   True        
        self.flag = True                               # !!! установил True
        self.c = 0                                           
# !!! добавил vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv      
        self.x = 123.4567
        self.spinBox_x = QDoubleSpinBox(self)  
        self.spinBox_x.move(440, 30)
        self.spinBox_x.setPrefix(" x --->   ")          
        self.spinBox_x.setDecimals(4)         
        self.spinBox_x.setMinimum(0)
        self.spinBox_x.setMaximum(999999999)
        self.spinBox_x.setSingleStep(0.65)
        self.spinBox_x.setValue(self.x)
        self.spinBox_x.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda value: self.valueChanged(value, 'x'))
            
        self.y = 77.40
        self.spinBox_y = QDoubleSpinBox(self)  
        self.spinBox_y.move(440, 70)
        self.spinBox_y.setPrefix(" y --->   ")          
        self.spinBox_y.setDecimals(4)         
        self.spinBox_y.setMinimum(0)
        self.spinBox_y.setMaximum(999999999)
        self.spinBox_y.setSingleStep(0.65)
        self.spinBox_y.setValue(self.y)
        self.spinBox_y.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda value: self.valueChanged(value, 'y'))

        self.w = 111
        self.spinBox_w = QDoubleSpinBox(self)  
        self.spinBox_w.move(440, 110)
        self.spinBox_w.setPrefix(" w --->   ")          
        self.spinBox_w.setDecimals(4)         
        self.spinBox_w.setMinimum(0)
        self.spinBox_w.setMaximum(999999999)
        self.spinBox_w.setSingleStep(0.65)
        self.spinBox_w.setValue(self.w)
        self.spinBox_w.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda value: self.valueChanged(value, 'w'))

        self.h = 211.234
        self.spinBox_h = QDoubleSpinBox(self)  
        self.spinBox_h.move(440, 150)
        self.spinBox_h.setPrefix(" h --->   ")          
        self.spinBox_h.setDecimals(4)         
        self.spinBox_h.setMinimum(0)
        self.spinBox_h.setMaximum(999999999)
        self.spinBox_h.setSingleStep(0.65)
        self.spinBox_h.setValue(self.h)
        self.spinBox_h.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda value: self.valueChanged(value, 'h'))            
        
    def valueChanged(self, value, v):
        if v == 'x':
            self.x = value
        elif v == 'y':
            self.y = value    
        elif v == 'w':
            self.w = value            
        elif v == 'h':
            self.h = value                 
        
        print(f"Current Value: {v} ---> {value}")       
        self.update()
# !!! добавил ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flag:
            qp = QPainter()
            qp.begin(self)
            self.drawRectangles(qp)
            qp.end()

    def drawRectangles(self, qp):
# ----------------> vvvvvv  vvvvvv  vvvvvv  vvvvvv  <------------------------
        qp.drawRect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
#        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked2)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.tab.flag = True
        try:
            a = int(self.lineEdit.text())
        except:
            a = 0
        b = a * 2
        c = a + b        
        self.tab.c = a + b
        self.update()

'''
    def onClicked2(self):
        self.tab_2.flag = True
        try:
            a = int(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        except:
            a = 0
        print(f'a = {a}') #
        b = a + 20  
        self.tab_2.c = b - a / 2
        print(f'self.tab_2.c = {self.tab_2.c}') #
        self.update()
'''        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При нажатии на Tab2 программа закрывается и в консоли выдаёт такую ошибку: 
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: @Arkadjan я уже вам писал. ВСЕГДА запускайте свое приложение в терминале/консоле/CMD и вы практический всегда будите получать реальную ошибку, если таковая у вас есть в коде.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User-PC\Documents\╚эЇ ъєЁё т7\app.py", line 152, in paintEvent
    self.drawRectangles(qp)
  File "C:\Users\User-PC\Documents\╚эЇ ъєЁё т7\app.py", line 157, in drawRectangles
    qp.drawRect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  drawRect(self, rect: QRectF): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawRect(self, x: int, y: int, w: int, h: int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  drawRect(self, r: QRect): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'

Comment: @Arkadjan я пока плохо понимаю, что у вас происходит. Какая у вас версия PyQt ? Какая у вас версия Python и какая ОС, все напишите?

Comment: PyQt5, Python 3.11, Windows 10

Comment: Самое интересное, что на телефоне всё нормально работает

Comment: @Arkadjan  вставьте    `print("Версия PyQt", QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR)`

Comment: Версия PyQt 5.15.9

Comment: @Arkadjan я не знаю чем вам еще помочь. Может попробуете перейти на PyQt6.

Comment: А как этот код будет выглядеть на PyQt6?

Comment: @Arkadjan вы разобрались с этим вопросом?

Comment: нет, проблема с импортом, в PyQt5 импортируется PyQt5.Qt, а в PyQt6 нет такого импорта

Comment: @Arkadjan я вам написал в комментарии к вашему последнему вопросу

Comment: Возвращаясь к этому вопросу, при использовании PyQt6 точно так же не рисует по нецелым числам, как при использовании PyQt5